# jQuery get parent with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am listening to clicks on an element with a specific class. When I click inside this element I want to get this element, not the children I clicked on. How do I avoid getting children back when I call

```
event.target
```

Here is fiddle I created to demonstrate the problem
https://jsfiddle.net/yxvfgkcs/

Since I get children back they get CSS applied to them instead of the parent.

How do I figure out I have clicked on a child of element and get the element with class `selectable` back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery you can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
var clickedField = $(e.target).closest(".selectable");
```

See updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24kzog9L/1/)